# kivy - save user input into a python list

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I`m having some difficulties understanding the interrelation between kivy and python.

I`m trying to do something super simple, as a first step, and it would be great if anybody could show an example:
How can I store input data into a python list once the user feeds-in data and press "enter"?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of this. User can input 3 things and they get stored in an array. If you want the user to input one thing and store it in an array you will have to split the input.

```
result = []
for i in range(3):
    answer = input()
    result.append(answer)

print(result)
```

NOTE: `input()` is `raw_input()` in python2.x

In `kivy`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class Screen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.input = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.input)
        self.input.bind(on_text_validate=self.print_input)
    def print_input(self, value):
        print(value.text)


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Screen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

This simple script will give you an input box and when you press enter it will print its text to terminal. You can easily store it in a list if you wish.

Comment: Thanks @Gabor, I know how this is done with raw_input. I`m struggling with kivy.

Comment: With `kivy` you will first have to build some kind of a frame where a user can input something. I am pretty sure there are tutorials for this, as it is not that straight forward

Comment: Yep, well, that`s the thing. There are few tutorials but none of them is particularly clear, or complete or exactly addresses this issue. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Perfect. I missed the input.bind line. Now it works - Thanks!

Comment: As a follow-up question, how can I do this using kivy language? Say I have a number of input variables that share some similar properties - how can I create a generic widget ij a kv file and call it from Python?